# 2D Array to Dictionary conversion

Tags: python

How to convert Input to Output ?

Input :   `mat=[[3, 37],[1, 41],[2, 37],[5, 41],[4, 35]]`

Output:   `mat={37:[3,2],41:[1,5],35:[4]}`

I have tried below code :

```
dic={}
x=[]
for i in mat:
    dic[i[1]]=list()
    dic[i[1]]=i[0]
```

Got This answer : `{37: 2, 41: 5, 35: 4}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault)

```
d = {}
for a,b in mat:
    d.setdefault(b, []).append(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `defaultdict` is a good practice when a default value is needed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

m = defaultdict(list)
for val, key in mat:
    m[key].append(val)
```

Comment: This is the approach I take most often.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dic={}
for i in mat:
    if i[1] not in dic:
        dic[i[1]] = []
    dic[i[1]].append(i[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The `setdefault()`/`append()` solution already works perfectly. An alternative would be to use the `list` `+` operator that concatenates two lists and returns the result:

```py
dic = {}
for i,j in mat:
    dic[j] = dic.get(j, []) + [i]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
dic={}
for i in mat:
    if dic.has_key(i[1]):
         dic[i[1]].append(i[0])
    else:
        dic[i[1]]=list()
        dic[i[1]].append(i[0])
```